# Folder Alignment Issue with Extjs4 Tree Panel

Tags: javascript, css, extjs4, panel

I'm fixing some issues with a Extjs4 tree panel, one of which is an alignment issue when expanding folders in the panel.

When a folders + expand icon is clicked the subfolders are loaded and appear below in the panel as desired, however on the first second of rendering they are further to the right, spaced slightly apart, then they are positioned to the left and properly aligned.

The aim is for this not to be seen as it looks terrible. I wish for the folder being expanded to produce its sub folders smoothly.

[image: Left: Whilst expanding. Right: After expanding]

**Left: Whilst expanding. Right: After expanding.**

I assume this is a CSS issue, however I've looked at all classes associated with these elements and have come up with nothing so far.

If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate them. I just want to understand the problem occurring.

Just ask if any extra info needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was CSS padding hidden away in a file previously overlooked. Then a secondary file applied new attributes changing the position instantly after loading.